# Java switch statement get to default on enum

Tags: java, android, enums

I have a Java (for Android) code similar to this one:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C
} 

String f(MyEnum e) {
    if (e == null) {
        return null;
    }

    switch(e) {
        case A: return "AA";
        case B: return "BB";
        case C: return "CC";
        default: throw new IllegalStateException("invalid enum");
    }
}
```

and I got the exception in the default clause thrown once! Can somebody explain if this is theoretically possible and how?

For example in C++ you can have an enum variable which value is non of the declared enum values, but I guess in Java you cannot do that, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: *"I got the exception in the default clause thrown once! Can somebody explain if this is theoretically possible..."* Well, if it **happened**, then it's theoretically possible.

Comment: Maybe your enum was updated and new values ware added, but your `switch` wasn't updated to handle them, so in case some new added value was used in `f` method you will get `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: No, it was not updated... and nobody even extended it!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the word **theoretically** was related to Java language rules, which was the question about - is there a way to have an enum variable which holds something not of the enum values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see how this could fail, but i would propose refactoring your enum to this:

```
enum MyEnum {
  A("AA"),
  B("BB"), 
  C("CC");

  private final String value;  

  public MyEnum(String value){
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String f(){
    return value;
  }
}
```

now you can still do the same operations, but it 100% safe to add new enums

```
public void foo(MyEnum enum){
  System.out.println(enum.f());
}
```